# Php scripts do not work on webhost

Tags: php

Good morning everybody,

I am experiencing an issue with php and mysql.

I can not post an image yet but below is exactly what is my issue:

LOCALHOST
/db
/php

WEBHOST
/db
/php

- LOCALHOST /db + LOCALHOST /php = WORK

  LOCALHOST /php + WEBHOST /db = WORK

  WEBHOST /php + WEBHOST /db = DOES NOT WORK

Also this is my script config.php:

```
   <?php
$host = "webhost";
$username = "adminDb"; 
$password = "passwordDb"; 
$db = "green_db";
$con = mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$db) or die("Can not connect to Server.");
?>
```

What would be the solution to make it work on my webhost?

Thanks by advance guys

Comment: Is MySQLi enabled on your server? What error are you getting, just the one from the query?

Comment: add mysqli_error to your connect function. `$con = mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$db) or die("Can not connect to Server. Reason: " . mysqli_error($con));`

Comment: @Andy Holmes : Yes MySli is enabled. Indeed i can query the online database from my localhost website.

Comment: @Volkan Ulukut: No error is retrieved actually. Only a blank page when i query the db from my online host. When i query it from my localhost it works well.

Comment: What are you expecting to see? This doesn't really tell us much lol

Comment: put `error_reporting(E_ALL);  ini_set('display_errors', '1');` at the head of your code, so you don't see a blank page, rather an explenatory error message.

Comment: but this is most probably a mysqli extension missing error like Andy pointed out.

Comment: Sorry guys to make you waste your time. Just called my web hoster... mysqli and mysql modules are not installed yet...